# Cant access container from browser

Tags: jenkins, devops

I'm trying to access the container from my laptop1 which is hosted on my other laptop2 Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.
I'm using putty to access ports. Through putty, I can access port 8080 but can't access other port 8081 where my container is hosted.

Here is my docker-compose file :
[docker-compose.yml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9WL61.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jenkins by default run on port 8080.
Please change your docker-compose `ports` section to

```
ports:
  - "8081:8080"
```

Comment: Thanks, @Amin Imani solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

Hello please do a netstat(sudo netstat
-lntup)inside your
jenkins  container (laptop2) and check wether it's listening on 8081 or not.

If it's listening then may be 3 reason you are unable access your jenkins container from laptop1

1. **Disable ufw(firewall) status and**

2.**selinux (disable state)**

3.if your are using azure, aws Or other cloud services check inbound traffic to allowed on 8081.

Comment: Thanks, @Mahesh, netstat command helped me to see the ports but the above solution solved the issue.